# Execute a maven plugin goal dependant on another plugin's goal being executed

Tags: java, maven, plugins

Due to the central build landscape in our organization, I can not easily influence the parameters with which a certain maven build is called. It is hard coded to:

```
mvn install someplugin:goal1 someplugin:goal2
```

Which is using my POM.xml that is based on a common parent POM of the organization.

As the tool being executed is not very clever. I need to call another plugin to generate additional sources (delombok plugin). I can not integrate that into the standard build though, as other static source code analysis tools fail otherwise (duplicate sources).

Is there any chance to make the plugin execute if (and only if) this other plugin is called?

Comment: if you do not add it to the standard build run ... what do you need it for and when should it run?